# mysql stored procedure encode out parameter string

Tags: mysql

I have this stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE get_mysql_user_pass(
  IN user_type VARCHAR(16),
  IN aes_passphrase VARCHAR(255),
  OUT mysql_user VARCHAR(16),
  OUT mysql_pass VARCHAR(32),
)
READS SQL DATA
SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN
  DECLARE aes_key VARCHAR(255);

  SET @aes_key = SHA1(aes_passphrase);

  SELECT 
    AES_DECRYPT(user_column,@aes_key), 
    AES_DECRYPT(pass_column,@aes_key) 
  INTO 
    mysql_user, mysql_pass 
  FROM my_table 
  WHERE my_column = user_type;
END;
```

- **The problem**:

If I use alpha_numeric like "hosi654dl25lkjdfwhatever" as mysql_pass  everything OK, but if I have something like this "rIµ°uþÁYfM09ÃÁôQÇOÅ°jýµàÈWfYf¡½4" as mysql_pass returns grabbled string like "rIÂµÂ°uÃ¾ÃYfM09ÃƒÃÃ´QÃ‡OÃ…Â°jÃ½ÂµÃ ÃˆWfYfÂ¡Â½4".

- I call it from PHP

  - **The question**:
    Is there any method to encode out string parameter "mysql_pass" and make it readable in PHP? (because the decryption seem be correct)

Comment: I can't fully grasp what you mean, perhaps you should edit the question and show the actual procedure call instead of describing it with words (use alpha_numeric? where?). In any case, I understand you encrypt binary data and decrypt it later successfully. But you want to display it for the user to see it. If the user can really make any use of that, you can generate an hexadecimal dump.

Comment: Sorry Alvaro this is due to my poor English. You understood correctly except that I will not show the user. I want to save this data into php variables and use them to connect to the database with another user - password. I have put HEX (AES_DECRYPT(pass_column,@aes_key)), it now returns me in php "7249C2B5C2B075C3BD34....". Now I do not know how to decode this in PHP so I save the original password in a PHP variable

Comment: SOLVED. (the last doubt with hex2bin() in php now all OK .

Comment: **PHP strings can handle binary data**. In fact, it you serialize it as text you'll break it. (Out of curiosity, how comes you have binary passwords in the first place?)

Comment: Doing `HEX()` + `hex2bin()` is like doing `123 + 5 - 5` :-?

Comment: but why it work ? Now Work as espected

Comment: I can't tell you. I don't know what data means or what it's used for. I don't know what values you call the procedure with. I don't know what manipulations you do with PHP. I don't know how it doesn't work.

Comment: So. I have the mysql_pass original string like "rIµ°uþÁ..." saved encrypted with mysql AESENCRYPT() in one BLOB column. To recover it I call this Stored Procedure from PHP  "CALL get_mysql_user_pass('in_user_type','in_aes_passphrase',@out_mysql_user,@out_mysql_pass,).After that I use $sql="SELECT @out_mysql_user,@out_mysql_pass"; $result = $my_statement->query($sql); $row=$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); Now Y try to assign this results to PHP variables.$user = $row["@out_mysql_user"]; $pass = $row["@out_mysql_pass"]. (I will continue in another comment.No more space)

Comment: When I try to use $pass to make another connecction (with new user-pass ) get Access denied for user 'test2'@'localhost' (using password: YES).That because $pass is a grabbled string not same to original. now when y use HEX (AES_DECRYPT(pass_column,@aes_key)) in my stored procedure (how you  suggested me above) and in php $pass = hex2bin($row["@out_mysql_pass"]). Everything Ok. No more errors.